# How can I close httpd open conncetion?

Tags: linux, memory, centos6, process, memory-usage

I have a lot of open connection of httpd and ram usage, how can i solve this?

[image: Running Proccess]

Comment: Restart `httpd` service, this will close all the connections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, these `httpd` children don't really use the amount of memory that `top` or `ps` reports in. Unix uses a complicated VM *copy-on-write* model, so when a process *forks* both parent and a child think they use the same amount of memory, so does `top` and `ps`. But in fact they *share* (please don't mix it with *IPC shared*) memory until some of them modifies a VM page, and only in latter case memory consumption is increasing.

If you would use FreeBSD, there is an utility called `tcpdrop`, which could kill any TCP established connection. Since it's a Linux, it doesn't have this decent tool. So, you either have to kill a particular child (this will kill the connection), but the master process could react inapropriate in some cases, or restart the entire daemon (this will kill all the connections).